# TypeError: _this.props.onUpdateShelf is not a function | React | Classbased component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, dom-events, onchange

I tried `this.bind(this)`, but still get the same error. When I tried to move book from one to another shelf, this error occurred.

This is my code and in `handleShelfChange` (line-11) got the error saying:

> **onUpdateShelf** is not a function.

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react'

class Book extends Component {
  state={
    value: ''
};
handleShelfChange= event => {
  const newValue=event.target.value;
    this.setState({value:newValue},() =>{
      this.props.onUpdateShelf(this.props.book,newValue)
    });
    
}
    render() {
      const{book,title,UpdateShelf}=this.props;
        return(
            <li>
            <div className="book">
              <div className="book-top">
                <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193,
                   backgroundImage: 'url("http://books.google.com/books/content?id=PGR2AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&imgtk=AFLRE73-GnPVEyb7MOCxDzOYF1PTQRuf6nCss9LMNOSWBpxBrz8Pm2_mFtWMMg_Y1dx92HT7cUoQBeSWjs3oEztBVhUeDFQX6-tWlWz1-feexS0mlJPjotcwFqAg6hBYDXuK_bkyHD-y&source=gbs_api")' }}></div>
                <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                  <select 
                  value={this.state.value}
                  onChange={this.handleShelfChange.bind(this)} > 
                  
                    <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
                    <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
                    <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                    <option value="read">Read</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
              <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
            </div>
          </li>
         
        )
    }
}

export default Book;
```

this is the parent component

```
import React from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import './App.css'
import BookShelf from './BookShelf'
//import Book from './Book'
import SearchPage from './SearchPage'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
   readBooks:[]
  }
componentDidMount() {
  BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
    this.setState({readBooks:books})
  })
}

UpdateShelf = (book,shelf) => {
  BooksAPI.update(book,shelf).then(books => {
    book.shelf = shelf;
  })
  let updateBook = (book) =>{
    this.setState(currState => ({
      readBooks: currState.book.filter(b=>
        b.id !== book.id
      )
    }));
  }
}
  render() {
    const{book,onUpdateShelf}=this.props;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Route exact path="/search"
        render={() =>(
          <SearchPage
          book={book}
          onUpdateShelf={onUpdateShelf} />
        )}/>

        <Route exact path="/"
        render={() =>(
<div className="list-books">
            <div className="list-books-title">
              <h1>MyReads</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="list-books-content">
              <BookShelf shelfType = "currentlyReading"
              onUpdateShelf={onUpdateShelf}
              book={this.state.readBooks.filter(b =>
                b.shelf === "currentlyReading"
              )} />
              <BookShelf shelfType = "wantToRead"
              onUpdateShelf={onUpdateShelf}
              book={this.state.readBooks.filter(b =>
                b.shelf === "wantToRead"
              )} />
              <BookShelf shelfType = "Read"
              onUpdateShelf={onUpdateShelf}
              book={this.state.readBooks.filter(b =>
                b.shelf === "read"
              )} />
              </div>
              <div className ="open-search">
                <Link to="/search">
                <button>Search Books</button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
        )} />
      </div>
      
    );
    }
}

export default BooksApp;
```

also i attached the bookshelf component

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react'
import Book from './Book'

class BookShelf extends Component {

    render() {
        const{onUpdateShelf,shelfType}=this.props;
        return(
            <div className="bookshelf">
                  <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelfType}</h2>
                  <div className="bookshelf-books">
                    <ol className="books-grid">
                        {this.props.book.map((book,key) =>
                        <Book
                        key={key}
                        book={book}
                        onUpdateShelf={onUpdateShelf} />
                        )}
                    </ol>
                    </div></div>
        )
    }
}
export default BookShelf;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are passing props in the parent component.

Comment: You have extended a class using ES6 syntax, and you haven't created a constructor or called the super constructor. Not sure if that will cause a problem. Also, you are not binding anything in your code, so certainly it will not find any object called this.props in your anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take one argument `props` to your class. then only you can access the values and functions in our class

```
class Book extends Component (props){
state={
```

change yor code like this

Comment: i tried the avove code. but it show props is not defined and when i tried this.props, its shows error like can't read props.

Comment: please help me to solve this issue.  when i tried to move book from one to another shelf i got the above error: onUpdateShelf is not a function